# In c++, conditional operator did not support pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, conditional-operator

**I'm sorry.This problem is caused by my careless.Please ignore it,thanks.**

I try to solve the problem post on LintCode,[Add Two Numbers](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/add-two-numbers/#).
At first,I try these codes:[first_code](http://codepad.org/jd77owpu),but I got Runtime Error,and Error Message TERMSIG= 11.
Then I change codes to these,[second_code](http://codepad.org/H0vy8P0D).**To my surprise,it worked .**
The only difference is :
[First]

```
l1 = (l1) ? nullptr : l1->next;
l2 = (l2) ? nullptr : l2->next;
```

[Second]

```
if(l1){
    l1 = l1->next;
}
else{
    l1=nullptr;
}
if(l2){
    l2 = l2->next;
}
else{
    l2=nullptr;
}
```

So I wonder whether conditional operator support pointer or not?
I try these simple codes:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int* a = nullptr;
    int b = 0;
    b = (a) ? 1 : 10;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

**It worked.**
But why did it failed on the problem on LintCode.
Did I overlook anything?

Comment: In your second line `l1 = (l2) ? nullptr : l2->next;` did you mean to assign to `l2`?

Comment: [First] is still not equivalent to [Second]. [First] should be `l1 = (l1) ? l1->next : nullptr;` or `l1 = (!l1) ? nullptr : l1->next;`

Comment: Take a look at [Ternary conditional operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = (l1) ? nullptr : l1->next;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (l1)
    l1 = nullptr;
else
    l1 = l1->next;
```

The problem should be obvious.

Many people would prefer to skip the alternative branch entirely,

```
if (l1)
    l1 = l1->next;
```

as assigning `nullptr` to a null pointer is unnecessary (and looks like something else was intended).

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code do different things.

The first one has two bugs. Firstly you don't assign l2 at all. Secondly, you dereference the pointer if it's null. The second version doesn't have these bugs.

You appear to be confused about the order of the operands of the conditional operator. The expression of the second operand is executed if the first operand is true, and the third operand is executed if the first is false.

> So I wonder whether conditional operator support pointer or not?

It does. You simply may not dereference a null pointer.